# How can I use glutInitDisplayMode() in a QGLWidget, so I can get anti-aliasing?

Tags: python, opengl, glut, antialiasing, qglwidget

I have a QGLWidget in which openGL objects are created. I want to get better anti-aliasing than I have now by using glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE | GLUT_DEPTH).
How can I impliment this function (in python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is an application framework that implements **the** GUI event loop. GLUT is an application, that implements **the** GUI event loop. There can be only *one* GUI event loop in a process. Hence Qt and GLUT can not be mixed.

Just configure QGLWidget with multisampling. Create a `QGLFormat` instance, call `setSampleBuffers(true)` on it, and pass it to the QGLWidget constructor.